# Access not enforced in .pbix only enforced in app.powerbi?

Tags: powerbi, ssas-tabular

When it comes to access, I see a discrepancy when opening a .pbix and when seeing the end result in app.powerbi

I consume data from a SSAS cube, and I have specifically a FALSE() dax filter for some users:
[image]

This works fine when the report is in app.powerbi but this access restriction does not get enforced when the user opens the .pbix.

Why is this behavior? Can it be changed?

Comment: Are they "the same" user when opening the file in both circumstances? Check what `USERPRINCIPALNAME()` is.

Comment: You were absolutely right! But I think is a bug in PowerBI... So if I use USERPRINICPALNAME I get an Id, but it doesnt match with the one I logged in with! So, I see an Id on the top right of Power BI app desktop different from the one given by USERPRINICPALNAME

Comment: Where is your SSAS model hosted?  On SQL Server Analysis Services? Azure Analysis Services? Power BI?